# React. How to change state only to current element after .map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When all list items are rendered I want that after click only clicked list item has been changed its style.

```
const [currentStyle, setCurrentStyle] = useState();

array.map(val => (<li style={currentStyle}>{val.name}</li>)
```

Comment: you mean the last `li` item you click ... you want it to have different style ?

Comment: @anees Nope. I mean the list item I clicked, i.e. if there are 5 list items and I clicked on second, so, second item would change it style. It can be buttons instead of list items for better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

I advise you to make another component for you items, that way it will be easier to  manage state for each item

for instance :

```
function YourComponent() {    
...
const [currentStyle, setCurrentStyle] = useState();
    ...
    array.map(val => (<ItemComponent style={currentStyle}>{val.name}</ItemComponent>)
...
}

function ItemComponent({style, children}) {
   const [changeStyle, setChangeStyle] = useState(false)
   return (
       <li onClick={() => {setChangeStyle(true)}} style={changeStyle ? style : null}>{children}</li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked!!

Comment: cool! nor problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do that has already been shared by Jimmy.
but if you are lazy you can do something like.

Note: Both approaches are different. If you manage that via subcomponents you will have to add extra logic to keep track of clicked items in the parent. (Still recommended)

But if you use this one you can have the clicked Items track in the component itself (clickedItems)

```js
const [currentStyle, setCurrentStyle] = useState();
const [clickedItems, setClickedItems] = useState([]);

array.map((val, index) => (<li onClick={() => 
    setClickedItems(clickedItems.find(i => i===index) ? clickedItems : [...clickedItems, index])}
    style={clickedItems.find(i => i===index) ? currentStyle : null}>{val.name}
</li>)
```

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: Whatever works :)

Comment: Thanks for your time!